# database structure - linking data

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to learn ASP.NET MVC5 so I decided to make somekind of review site. I want to add diffrent console / pc games and movies etc. For the Games table I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Games] (
    [GameId]     INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]  NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Genre]  NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Format] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Games] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([GameId] ASC)
);
```

---

I have the same code for the movie table, 
And here are is the user table I got from MVC:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

But my question is, how do I link the movies / games to the user? 
Do I just have to add a FK on the game / movie table, or should the FK go on the user table?

And the next thing, how would I store rating, (INT) and reviews (NVARCHAR) ? 
I think it would be best if I made a spefic table for this and than link the table to the game / movie table?

And a follow up question to that. How do I link these two?

And once they are linked... how would I go ahead and populate my database? I would assume I could make some sort of script to populate them for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AspNetUsers
------
Id (PK)

Game
------
Id (PK)

Review
------
Id (PK)
GameId (FK)
UserId (FK)
```

or make a composite key if a user can only review a game 1 time

```
Review
------
GameId (PK)
UserId (PK)
```

but if you want to have Movies and Games you could do

```
Review
------
Id (PK)
GameId (FK NULL)
MovieId (FK NULL)
UserId (FK)
```

Look into Table Relationships

Comment: The only problem i'm having is that I get the AspNetUsers from mvc5 and I can't change that table.

Comment: You can change that. Look into using the UserManager and RoleManager classes for AspNetMembership. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605872.aspx. This can expose Entity Framework objects to wire up to those membership tables.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should actually have a separate join table with a foreign key to the movie and one to the user, since you're dealing with a M2M relationship here: users can review many movies and movies can be reviewed by many users. Likewise for games.

However, since you're starting off with MVC you're actually putting the cart before the horse. While you can use an existing database with Entity Framework, it's much preferable to let Entity Framework manage your database schema for you based on the code you write. Then, when you make changes to your classes, you can create migrations that will update the schema accordingly.

Just do a search for something like "entity framework code first". You'll find a wealth of articles and tutorials explaining how to get going.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the association between users and games is that users will write game reviews. If this is so, a user can review multiple games, and many users can review a single game. But you are missing a review table that should be the relationship between the two tables you have listed.